# Why is 'Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' showing despite no nil values being present?

Tags: swift, error-handling, swiftui, swift-optionals

I've been investigating this error for a while and I am still struggling to find an answer.

I understand the concept behind this error yet I don't understand why it is still notifying me even though I feel as if I have removed any nil values from the *equation* (<- phrase, not code).

```
struct NickName: View {

var name: String = ""
@AppStorage("current_user") var user = ""

var body: some View {
    
    Text(String(name.first!)) //It notifies me here, i.e. 'Thread 1: Fatal error...'
        .fontWeight(.heavy)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        .background((name == user ? Color.blue : Color.green).opacity(0.5))
        .clipShape(Circle())
}}
```

This structure is passed through a series of views where it should be presented in a messaging interface.

Thanks for any help, I feel as though I've just been looking at this the wrong way or maybe I am missing something and it is an easy fix :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var name: String = ""` is an empty `String`.

`name.first` should return you first `Character` in the `String` optionally if it is present.

For your example, since this is an empty `String`, it will be `nil`.

When you force cast something that is `nil`, it will crash your app with the message that you are seeing.

Solution :

```
Text(String(name.first ?? ""))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was so trivial so I'm sorry to take up your time: It worked! I am quite new to swift as I have had to learn it for my senior year project in school and some of these basic things slip me sometimes. You've helped immeasurably as I can now continue with my Major Work. Thanks :)